# Monospaced question/answer editor on mobile

Tags: feature-request, android-app, mobile-web, ios-app, fonts

The iOS and Android apps, as well as the mobile website, use a text area with a proportional-width font for the question/answer editor. Please make them use fixed-width fonts, especially on programming-related sites.

Comment: Devil's advocate: monospace fonts take up more space, showing you less text on the constrained display of a mobile device. Preview already shows it correctly

Comment: @mhlester The mobile interface has no preview feature.

Comment: Oh, good point. Considering they've asked us to make ios and android feature requests independent, I'd say mobile web should even more so be its own request